# Bezout-type theorem for $p$-adic analytic plane curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, p-adic-analysis, p-adic-numbers, rigid-analytic-geometry

Let $p$ be a prime, and let $f,g \in \mathbb{Z}_p[[x,y]]$ be power series convergent on all of $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Suppose that the intersection of the analytic plane curves cut out by $f$ and $g$ is finite; i.e., suppose that $\#V(f,g) < \infty$, where we count points of intersection with multiplicity.

**Question**: Let $f,g$ be as above. Is there an analogoue of Bezout's theorem that gives an upper bound on $\#V(f,g)$ in terms of some natural invariants of $f,g$?

**Progress**: A first step would be to define some notion of degree for power series. Here is my naive attempt to do so:

1. Define the degree of a single-variable power series $h(x)$ to be the number of its zeros (counted with multiplicity) if $h \not\equiv 0$, and to be $-\infty$ if $h \equiv 0$. Equivalently, define the degree of $h$ to be the degree of the Weierstrass polynomial of $h$, i.e., the polynomial occurring in the factorization of $h$ given by the Weierstrass preparation theorem. Equivalently still, define the degree of $h$ to be the $x$-coordinate of the bottom-right corner of the Newton polygon of $h$.
2. Define the *max-degree* of a two-variable power series $f(x,y)$, denoted $\operatorname{maxdeg}(f)$, as follows:
   $$\operatorname{maxdeg}(f) := \max_{\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{Z}_p} \max\left\{\deg V\big(f(x,\alpha x + \beta)\big),\,\deg V\big(f(\alpha y + \beta,y)\big)\right\}.$$
   In other words, $\operatorname{maxdeg}(f)$ is the maximum of the degrees of the single-variable power series obtained by intersecting $f$ with all possible lines. Note that if $f \not\equiv 0$, then $\operatorname{maxdeg}(f)$ is well-defined and finite, because the function
   $$(\alpha,\beta) \mapsto \max\left\{\deg V\big(f(x,\alpha x + \beta)\big),\,\deg V\big(f(\alpha y + \beta,y)\big)\right\}$$
   is a locally constant function on the compact set $\mathbb{Z}_p^2$. This is by way of contrast with the complex-analytic setting, where analytic plane curves can have infinite degree (see [Is there a "Bezout's theorem" for analytic curves?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14141/is-there-a-bezouts-theorem-for-analytic-curves)).

Given any notion of degree, such as the one formulated above, it would be nice for an analogue of Bezout's theorem to hold with respect to that notion. For example, is it true that $\#V(f,g)$ can be bounded by some polynomial in $\operatorname{maxdeg}(f)$ and $\operatorname{maxdeg}(g)$? At the very least, if $g$ is linear, then $\#V(f,g) \leq \operatorname{maxdeg}(f)$.

Otherwise, perhaps there's some way to bound $\#V(f,g)$ in terms of the Newton polytopes of $f$ and $g$? Any references on intersection theory for analytic varieties would be very helpful too.

Comment: I believe the Joe Rabinoff has some work on this topic e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.2665. Also, you might be able to find some useful things in Section 5 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.07057.pdf. I believe that in order to get bounds in terms of the Newton polytopes you need to understand a bit about the tropicalization of the common zeros.

Comment: @JacksonMorrow Yes, I think you're right; Rabinoff's work gives bounds on $\#V(f,g)$ in terms of the "mixed volume" of the Newton polytopes of $f,g$, but only when the tropicalizations of the common zeros are isolated in the intersection of the tropicalizations of $f,g$. This technical condition makes the result not quite as satisfactory or easy to use as Bezout.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.5733 looks like it might be relevant to the question what can be said when the tropical intersection points are not isolated.

Comment: @Ashvin Yes you are correct that there is this technical assumption concerning isolated points in the intersection of the tropical intersections, which is not as satisfactory. The reference Michael Stoll discusses the stable tropical intersection, which is a well-defined number. If I recall, the issue with this approach and your question is that it is not clear how the stable tropical intersection is related to "natural" invariants of $f$ and $g$.